# Rx extension - creating minute bar from sequence

Tags: time, system.reactive, intervals, minute

I have a sequence where values are generated at random times (real time stock market prices). I have a requirement to find the highest and lowest value of the sequence between a one minute period. I know you can use something like Buffer for this. 
But the minute window should start with 00 seconds and finish at 59 seconds. e.g. the minute should start from 8:00:00 and finish at 8:00:59 the second minute should start from 8:01:00 to 8:01:59. Can we do this with Rx? Thanks. Vipter

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
var query =
    source
        .Publish(ss =>
            ss
                .GroupByUntil(
                    x => x.Timestamp.ToUnixTimeSeconds() / 60,
                    x => x.Value,
                    x => ss.Where(s => x.Key != s.Timestamp.ToUnixTimeSeconds() / 60))
                .Select(gxs => gxs.ToArray().Select(xs => new
                {
                    min = xs.Min(), max = xs.Max()
                })));
```